# Prev and next buttons in modal gallery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, gallery

I found modal gallery example and tried to adapt it to my needs but now I have a problem with the prev - next buttons... Do you have any suggestion? (javascript newbee)

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/skulptron/pen/yLMBWro?editors=1010)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/385997/pexels-photo-385997.jpeg" onclick="openLightbox(this);toSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow preview">
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/574521/pexels-photo-574521.jpeg" onclick="openLightbox(this);toSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow preview">
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/386009/pexels-photo-386009.jpeg" onclick="openLightbox(this);toSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow preview">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="Lightbox" class="modal">
 <span class="close pointer" onclick="closeLightbox()">&times;</span>
    
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="slide">
   <img id="modal-slides" class="image-slide" alt="END OF SLIDESHOW GROUP" />
  </div>

  <a class="previous" onclick="changeSlide(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="changeSlide(1)">&#10095;</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlide(slideIndex);

function openLightbox(element) {
  document.getElementById('Lightbox').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("modal-slides").src = element.src; 
}
function closeLightbox() {
  document.getElementById('Lightbox').style.display = 'none';
}
function changeSlide(n) {
    showSlide(slideIndex += n);
}
function toSlide(n) {
    showSlide(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlide(n) {
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1; 
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
}
```

I have tried various options but my javascript knowledge is poor. I am grateful for any help.

**EDIT**

prettyInPink I tried to do what you suggested, here is example:

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/skulptron/pen/YzZXgNJ)

When I open modal by clicking in last picture (number 8), everything is OK, but when modal is opened with any other picture, PREV - NEXT doesn't works right... Displayed images are in some way random... Any suggestion?

Comment: What does your ```toSlide``` function do? Also when you are calling the ```showslide``` function, why are you using ```display: none;``` and ```display: block;```? Shouldn't you simply be modifying the ```src``` attribute of the ```#modal-slides``` image?

Comment: @prettyInPink thanx for your comment, I have supplemented the question in relation to your suggestions.

Comment: I have added an example below, hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data attributes set to your images `data-image` and target those.

```js
    let _body = document.querySelector('body'),
        galleryImg = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery img'),
        modalWindow = document.getElementById('modal-gall'),
        modalImg = document.getElementById('modal-slides'),
        closeModal = document.getElementById('closem'),
        nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextm'),
        prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevm'),
        curSlide;
    
    galleryImg.forEach((img) => {
      img.addEventListener('click', function() {
        curSlide = Number(this.dataset.image);
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        _body.classList.add('modal-open');
      });
    });

    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      curSlide === galleryImg.length ? curSlide = 1 : curSlide += 1
      modalImg.src = document.querySelector('.gallery img[data-image="'+(curSlide)+'"]').src;
    });

    prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      curSlide === 1 ? curSlide = galleryImg.length : curSlide -= 1
      modalImg.src = document.querySelector('.gallery img[data-image="'+(curSlide)+'"]').src;
    });

    closeModal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      _body.classList.remove('modal-open');
    });
```

```css
      body {
        font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #514c5c;
        color: white;
      }
      .gall-container {
          text-align: left;
          padding: 0 2% 0 2%; 
          width: auto;
      }
      .gall-text {
          text-align: left;
          font-size: 16px;
          padding: 50px 5px 2px 5px; 
          width: 100%;
      }
      .gallery {
          display: flex; 
          height: auto; 
          flex-wrap: wrap; 
          justify-content: left; 
          align-content: flex-start; 
          padding: 5px 0 5px 0; 
      }
      .gallery > img {
          max-width: 90vw;
          max-height: 200px;
          cursor: zoom-in;
          display: block;
          padding: 6px; 
      }
      #modal-gall {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 8px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.97);
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .modal-open #modal-gall {
        display: block;
      }

      .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      #modal-slides {
          display: block;
          max-width:100%; 
          max-height: calc(100vh - 16px);
          margin: auto;
      }
      #closem {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #9e97b1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        right: 0px;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        padding: 2px 16px 8px 16px;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: #29272e;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      #closem:hover,
      #closem:focus {
        color: red;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #prevm,
      #nextm {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 46%;
        width: auto;
        padding: 10px 22px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        color: #9e97b1;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        background-color: #29272e;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      #prevm {
        left: 0;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
      }
      #nextm {
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
      }
      #prevm:hover,
      #nextm:hover {
        background-color: #322c42;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="gall-container">
      <div class="gall-text"><b style="color: silver; font-size: 120%;">EXIBITION 02</b>
          <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc egestas mauris rhoncus, aliquam turpis a, tempus erat. Proin sit amet cursus felis. Etiam rhoncus tortor id nunc viverra, sed imperdiet leo congue. Nam tristique elementum gravida. In efficitur odio at lorem pretium, at lobortis dui hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse eu erat facilisis, ullamcorper mi id, semper libero. Suspendisse iaculis in ipsum sed luctus. Duis cursus varius dui at fringilla. 
          <br><span style="color: #b1afaf; font-size: 80%;">>>  Cras non commodo massa.</span><br>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sxLJ4WgV/08.jpg" alt="08 Image description" data-image="8">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/vm73wD3z/07.jpg" alt="07 Image description" data-image="7">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qvyG2zVT/06.jpg" alt="06 Image description" data-image="6">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MTWt6xL8/05.jpg" alt="05 Image description" data-image="5">
          <div class="gall-text"><b style="color: silver; font-size: 120%;">EXIBITION 01</b> 
              <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc egestas mauris rhoncus, aliquam turpis a, tempus erat. Proin sit amet cursus felis. Etiam rhoncus tortor id nunc viverra, sed imperdiet leo congue. Nam tristique elementum gravida. In efficitur odio at lorem pretium, at lobortis dui hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse eu erat facilisis, ullamcorper mi id, semper libero. Suspendisse iaculis in ipsum sed luctus. Duis cursus varius dui at fringilla. 
              <br> <span style="color: #b1afaf; font-size: 80%;">>>  Cras non commodo massa.</span><br>
          </div>
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HsJzs66j/04.jpg" alt="04 Image description" data-image="4">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jq3vbpQG/03.jpg" alt="03 Image description" data-image="3">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Xqq85L3H/02.jpg" alt="02 Image description" data-image="2">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/C1m7dXyn/01.jpg" alt="01 Image description" data-image="1">
      </div>
      <div id="modal-gall">
          <a href="#close" id="closem">&times;</a>
          <div class="modal-content">
              <img id="modal-slides" alt="">
          </div>
          <a id="prevm">&#10094;</a>
          <a id="nextm">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Woow ... You gave me a complete solution! I just started learning about external javascript code and you gave me a code based on which it will be even more interesting to learn ... Thank you very much!